# R: Keep row from duplicates (several columns) based on condition

Tags: r, duplicates

Basically I want to: 
If rows are duplicated on the combination of some specific columns, then keep only the row that has the lowest value on another column.

Example data (there's a lot more variance in my real data):

```
ID  BilagNr Henstand    Aftale  Belob   RP  Pos Dps Udlign  rykkedage
1   111     01-01-2017   1111   100     YA   1   1               10
1   122     02-01-2017   1222   100     YA   1        1          40
1   111     01-07-2017   1111   100     YA   1   1              100
2   222     01-01-2017   2121   299     YA   1        4          5
2   222     01-01-2017   2121   299     YA   1        4          98
2   212     01-05-2017   7654   299     BS   1                   3
3   333     01-08-2017   7654   345     BS   2                   45
4   444     01-01-2017   7654   345     BS   3   1    4          68
4   411     09-01-2017   7654   345     BS   1        4          43
5   555     01-01-2017   5555   700     BS   1                   13
5   555     01-01-2017   5555   700     BS   1                   67
6   666     01-01-2017   4720   100     BS   1                   23
6   666     03-01-2017   1234   100     BS   2        1          23
6   666     07-08-2017   1234   120     BS   3   1    1          23
7   777     01-01-2017   1234   90      BS   1        1          23
7   777     01-01-2017   1234   90      BS   1        1         199
```

So I want to only keep these:

```
ID  BilagNr Henstand    Aftale  Belob   RP  Pos Dps Udlign  rykkedage
1   111     01-01-2017   1111   100     YA   1   1               10
1   122     02-01-2017   1222   100     YA   1        1          40
2   222     01-01-2017   2121   299     YA   1        4          5
2   212     01-05-2017   7654   299     BS   1                   3
3   333     01-08-2017   7654   345     BS   2                   45
4   444     01-01-2017   7654   345     BS   3   1    4          68
4   411     09-01-2017   7654   345     BS   1        4          43
5   555     01-01-2017   5555   700     BS   1                   13
6   666     01-01-2017   4720   100     BS   1                   23
6   666     03-01-2017   1234   100     BS   2        1          23
6   666     07-08-2017   1234   120     BS   3   1    1          23
7   777     01-01-2017   1234   90      BS   1        1          23
```

In other words:

If the rows are **duplicated** in a combination of the columns **ID, BilagNr, Henstand, Aftale, Belob, RP, Pos, Dps, Udlign** *then* keep only one of the duplicated rows and choose this from the condition that **rykkedage** has to be the **smallest** of the duplicated rows.

I hope it makes sense.

[image: Maybe this photo will help]

Furthermore, is it possible to add a code that keeps those duplicated rows that has the same value in rykkedage? I have a large dataset, and I'm not sure if this is even a problem.

Thank you!

Comment: I have asked something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182871/combine-rows-with-same-id-and-delete-duplicated-rows)

Comment: your second  question is not very clear.  Could you show the expected for that one

Comment: If for example I have a row with duplicates through all columns - also in rykkedage. So let's sat id 1 had a fourth row with the same data as the duplicate that I remove (rykkedage=100). Then I wouldn't know which one to keep, and I'd have to look more deeply in to that. (There's more variables)

Comment: Just wanted to point that in your input example, the `Henstand` dates differ between the 'IDs that are 1.  That is the reason when we do group by with Henstand as well, the rykkedage 100 remains

Comment: In that case, you can create a logical column `df1 %>% group_by(ID, BilagNr, Henstand, Aftale, Belob, RP, Pos, Dps, Udlign) %>% mutate(Flag = rykkedage %in% min(rykkedage))`

Answer (score 4):

We can group by 'ID', 'BilagNr', ..., 'Udlign', and then `slice` the rows with the index of the minimum value in 'rykkedage'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID, BilagNr, Henstand, Aftale, Belob, RP, Pos, Dps, Udlign) %>%
   slice(which.min(rykkedage))
# A tibble: 13 x 10
# Groups:   ID, BilagNr, Henstand, Aftale, Belob, RP, Pos, Dps, Udlign [13]
#      ID BilagNr Henstand   Aftale Belob RP      Pos   Dps Udlign rykkedage
#   <int>   <int> <chr>       <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int>  <int>     <int>
# 1     1     111 01-01-2017   1111   100 YA        1     1     NA        10
# 2     1     111 01-07-2017   1111   100 YA        1     1     NA       100
# 3     1     122 02-01-2017   1222   100 YA        1    NA      1        40
# 4     2     212 01-05-2017   7654   299 BS        1    NA     NA         3
# 5     2     222 01-01-2017   2121   299 YA        1    NA      4         5
# 6     3     333 01-08-2017   7654   345 BS        2    NA     NA        45
# 7     4     411 09-01-2017   7654   345 BS        1    NA      4        43
# 8     4     444 01-01-2017   7654   345 BS        3     1      4        68
# 9     5     555 01-01-2017   5555   700 BS        1    NA     NA        13
#10     6     666 01-01-2017   4720   100 BS        1    NA     NA        23
#11     6     666 03-01-2017   1234   100 BS        2    NA      1        23
#12     6     666 07-08-2017   1234   120 BS        3     1      1        23
#13     7     777 01-01-2017   1234    90 BS        1    NA      1        23
```